# Unable to evaluate the expression. An error occurred that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80004002)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016

I use `Visual Studio 2015` and `SQL Server 2016` and also I use [COZYROC](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/file-transfer-task) component for SSIS for working with SFTP.

I what move all files between two folder in SFTP. For that. I have created a variable (V_FilesNameList) with object data type. Then, I have used a `COZYROC SFTP Task` for getting the list of files name on SFTP server:

[image]

This is a configuration for above component :

[image]

Then, I have created a foreach loop on my variable (V_FilesNameList).
And inside the loop I want to change the name of each file and copy it to the new address.

[image]

[image]

But I have this error :

```
Error: ForEach Variable Mapping number 1 to variable 
    "User::V_File_Name_Old" cannot be applied.
Error: ForEach Variable Mapping number 919997528 
     to variable "껤ʧ" cannot be applied.
```

And when I want to watch the value inside the my variable (V_FilesNameList) in Watch windows, I have this error :

```
    V_FilesNameList Unable to evaluate the expression. An error occurred 
      that usually indicates a corrupt installation (code 0x80004002). 
    If the problem persists, repair your Visual Studio installation via 
       'Add or Remove Programs' in Control Panel.
```

Why I have those errors? And how can I move the files between two folder in SFTP server with SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

> And how can I move the files between two folder in SFTP server with
>   SSIS?

1. Download Files (File Transfer Task CozyRoc) to your file system inside some folder (configurable Project Parameter)
2. Now using the Foreach Loop Container (Set Enumerator -> **ForEach File Enumerator** ) get complete file path for each file.
3. Using File Transfer Task move file to the SFTP.
4. Using File System Task delete all files from the local folder (Where files are download in step 1).

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Variable Mappings` in your `foreach loop container`, if the object `V_FilesNameList` contains a list string of file names, then the variable in your `Variable Mappings` should be in `string` data type, so that they could be mapped correctly. I am guessing your mapped variable `variable 껤ʧ` is not set correctly.

Comment: The question is: how can I check the value of my variable V_FilesNameList. When I want to check it, I have the second error.

Comment: You could add a breakpoint at `Pre-execute` for `Foreach Loop Container`, when the package hits the breakpoint, use a `Watch Window` from `Debug-windows-watch`, before the loop starts to iterate, you could observer what is actually get stored in that object

Comment: I had done it. But in Watch window when i want to see the content of this variable I have the second error.

Comment: Then obviously your object is not set correctly. What did you try to parse to the object?

Comment: In second image of my question you can see what is in my variable. With the COZYROC SFTP task I have tried to get the list of all files in SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error `to variable "껤ʧ" cannot be applied` when I was working with a ForEach loop container too. The problem is with NULL's in the ResultVariable. Try to handle the NULLS returned from source. In my case, the object variable was populated from a query so all I had to do was use ISNULL sql function.